# Use JQuery to display only one row of a table on a seperate page on the same domain

Tags: jquery

I have an html table on one page in our domain, and I would like to use JQuery to display a single row, based on the current date. I have gotten to the point where I can isolate the row I need based on the date if the table exists on the same page with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.get('oncalltable.html', function(res){
    var d = new Date();

    var month = d.getMonth()+1;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    var oncalldate = ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' + year % 100;

    var $tableElement = $(res.responseText).find('table.confluenceTable');

    var search = oncalldate;
    var todayoncall = $("span").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == search;
    }).parents('tr');

console.log(oncalldate, search,todayoncall);

$('.test span').html(todayoncall);
});
</script>

<div class="test"><p>Today: <span></span></p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I source this table from another page?

Table is in the following format (auto-generated by Confluence), if that helps:

```
<div class=\"table-wrap\">
<table class=\"confluenceTable\">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>Product </strong>
                    <strong style=\"line-height: 1.4285;\">Reliability</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong style=\"line-height: 1.4285;\">(
                        <a href=\"/display/Product+Reliability+Team\">contact</a> info)
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <strong style=\"line-height: 1.4285;\">Product </strong>
                <strong style=\"line-height: 1.4285;\">Reliability</strong>
                <p>
                    <strong>(
                        <a href=\"/display/Product+Reliability+Team\">contact</a> info)
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"5\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p style=\"text-align: center;\">
                    <strong>Storage Engine</strong>
                </p>
                <p> </p>
                <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <strong>Infrastructure</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">On-Call Engineer</td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <span>On-Call Engineer</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">On-Call Lead</td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <span>On-Call Engineer</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <span>On-Call Lead</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p> </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>6 am – </strong>
                    <strong style=\"line-height: 1.4285;\">2 pm UTC </strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong style=\"line-height: 1.4285;\">(
                        <strong>8 hours)</strong>
                    </strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>SpB : 9 am – 5 pm</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>2 pm – 10 pm UTC</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>(8 hours)</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Boston: 9 am – 5 pm EST </strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>/ 10am – 6pm EDT</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>6 am UTC – 2 pm UTC (
                        <strong>8 hours)</strong>
                    </strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>SpB         : 9 am – 5 pm</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Shanghai : 2 pm – 10 pm</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>2 pm UTC – 10 pm UTC (8 hours)</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Boston: 9 am – 5 pm EST / 10am – 6pm EDT</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>
                        <strong>Texas: 8 am – 4 pm CST / 9am – 5pm CDT</strong>
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>10 pm UTC – 6 am UTC (8 hours)</strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Seattle: 2 pm – 10 pm PST / 3pm – 11pm PDT</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\"> </td>
            <td colspan=\"1\" class=\"confluenceTd\">
                <p>
                    <strong>4 am UTC </strong>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>(24 hours)</strong>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <span>09/03/16</span>
            </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">Sat</td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\"> </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\"> </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <p>
                    <a class=\"confluence-userlink user-mention\" data-username=\"user1\" href=\"/display/~user1\" data-linked-resource-id=\"40407182\" data-linked-resource-version=\"2\" data-linked-resource-type=\"userinfo\" data-base-url=\"https://wikipage.com:8443\">user1</a>
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <a class=\"confluence-userlink user-mention\" data-username=\"user2\" href=\"/display/~user2\" data-linked-resource-id=\"24217157\" data-linked-resource-version=\"2\" data-linked-resource-type=\"userinfo\" data-base-url=\"https://wikipage.com:8443\">user2</a>
            </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <a class=\"confluence-userlink user-mention\" data-username=\"user3\" href=\"/display/~user3\" data-linked-resource-id=\"54956587\" data-linked-resource-version=\"2\" data-linked-resource-type=\"userinfo\" data-base-url=\"https://wikipage.com:8443\">user3</a>
            </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <a class=\"confluence-userlink user-mention\" data-username=\"user4\" href=\"/display/~user4\" data-linked-resource-id=\"30030931\" data-linked-resource-version=\"1\" data-linked-resource-type=\"userinfo\" data-base-url=\"https://wikipage.com:8443\">user4</a>
            </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <a class=\"confluence-userlink user-mention\" data-username=\"user5\" href=\"/display/~user5\" data-linked-resource-id=\"30023135\" data-linked-resource-version=\"2\" data-linked-resource-type=\"userinfo\" data-base-url=\"https://wikipage.com:8443\">user5</a>
                <span> </span>
            </td>
            <td class=\"highlight-grey confluenceTd\" colspan=\"1\" data-highlight-colour=\"grey\">
                <a class=\"confluence-userlink user-mention\" data-username=\"user6\" href=\"/display/~user6\" data-linked-resource-id=\"35622102\" data-linked-resource-version=\"3\" data-linked-resource-type=\"userinfo\" data-base-url=\"https://wikipage.com:8443\">user6</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: On your other page, you might have to get the content of this page (that includes the table) via an AJAX request and parse the content to get the row

Comment: Yeah but how? This is my first time dabbling in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the page with table has the url:

```
http://example.com/pagewithtable
```

and the page you want to include the row in has the url:

```
http://example.com/rowpage
```

inside that `rowpage` you should have the javascript code that gets the content from the other page:

```
$.get('http://example.com/pagewithtable', function(res){
  var $tableElement = $(res.responseText).find('table.confluenceTable');
  //then do what you need to do to select the row that you want
  var rowHtml = $('tr:first', $tableElement); //an example
  ....
  ....


  //finally append it to a div in the page
  $('.some-div').append(rowHtml);
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting null for todayoncall. I've updated my code in the question.